# Searching a document for numbers and printing the line above

Tags: python

I have existing data in a file that looks like this:

```
d893ecee58ee4d6f1ca56a358d2e6287
69
ae0d10efd7663c734b9ea66cec5aaa44
100
c9136ba49f4b1a8e89d6ed35cac95f7c
100
67c1431d8a06d7b2e31g86874b757eeb
0
8478b9587875f65d5afe54f541bada61
11
```

What i'd like to do is search the document for any line with a number value greater than 30 and print the line above that number.

Here's what I have now :

```
with open ('somefile.txt','r') as f, open('newfile.txt','w') as fnew:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if line.startswith('1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or '5' or '6' or '7' or '8' or '9' or '10' or '11' or '12' or '13' or '14' or '15' or '16' or '17' or '18' or '19' or '20' or '21' or '22' or '23' or '24' or '25' or '26' or '27' or '28' or '29' or '30'):
                fnew.write(line -1)
```

I know this isn't the cleanest script but i just want something that works.

Comment: There are better ways to do this but, for starters, what result are you getting?

Comment: Run in your Python interpreter: `'1' or '2'`. Do you get what you expected? Also, `line -1` doesn't make sense _at all_ as it subtracts an integer from a string. Even worse, `fnew.print` doesn't exist.

Comment: The code/pseudocode shown here does `<= 30` rather than `> 30`.

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous line as you are iterating over the input file. And I would suggest you use something like `if line.strip().isdigit()`. The way your code is written now, it will inadvertently match a lot of data lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I would take, which assumes your input data is regular:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            data = next(f).strip()
            number = next(f).strip()
        except StopIteration:
            # EOF
            break
        number = int(number)
        if number > 30:
            # TODO: Write data to other file
            print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different approach , then collect data and values in a dict and then iterate over dict if key is large than 30 then fetch the value:

```
values={}
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    sub = []
    for line in f:

        sub.append(line.strip())
        if len(sub) == 2:
            if int(sub[1]) not in values:
                values[int(sub[1])]=[sub[0]]
            else:
                values[int(sub[1])].append(sub[0])

            sub=[]




for key,value in values.items():
    if key>30:
        print(key,value)
```

output:

```
100 ['ae0d10efd7663c734b9ea66cec5aaa44', 'c9136ba49f4b1a8e89d6ed35cac95f7c']
69 ['d893ecee58ee4d6f1ca56a358d2e6287']
```

step by step:

First collect all values and num in dict :

```
values={}
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    sub = []
    for line in f:

        sub.append(line.strip())
        if len(sub) == 2:
            if int(sub[1]) not in values:
                values[int(sub[1])]=[sub[0]]
            else:
                values[int(sub[1])].append(sub[0])

            sub=[]
```

it will give :

```
{0: ['67c1431d8a06d7b2e31g86874b757eeb'], 11: ['8478b9587875f65d5afe54f541bada61'], 100: ['ae0d10efd7663c734b9ea66cec5aaa44', 'c9136ba49f4b1a8e89d6ed35cac95f7c'], 69: ['d893ecee58ee4d6f1ca56a358d2e6287']}
```

Now iterate over this dict and fetch value of that key if key >30

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of list comprehensions and itertools.compress to solve this.

Your file format has to follow strictly what you posted here though.

```
import itertools
# zero-line is the ID, 1st line is the number. NO empty lines in between.

text = '''d893ecee58ee4d6f1ca56a358d2e6287
69
ae0d10efd7663c734b9ea66cec5aaa44
100
c9136ba49f4b1a8e89d6ed35cac95f7c
100
67c1431d8a06d7b2e31g86874b757eeb
0
8478b9587875f65d5afe54f541bada61
11
'''

lines = text.split("\n") # list of all lines - you can get that from 
                         # file with readlines()

data = lines[0::2]       # your data is in every 2nd line starting at 0

                         # your numbers are in every 2nd line starting on 1
nums = [1 if (int(x) > 30) else 0 for x in lines[1::2] ]

# the list comprehension creates a list of 0 and 1 - 1 if number > 30
# itertools.compress does the lifing for you 

result = itertools.compress(data,nums)

print(list(result))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress

Compress utilizes 2 lists and returns an iterator over list1 that includes only elements that have a `True` in the other list.

Without itertools:

```
result2 = []
for idx in range(len(lines)):
    try: 
        if idx%2 == 1 and int(lines[idx])>30:
            result2.append(lines[idx-1])
    except:
        print("Error at line: ",idx, " unable to convert to int for input'", lines[idx],"'")


print(result2)
```

Comment: This seems like a neat but overly complex way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems with your approach. Here's my attempt:

```
def line_gt_30(line):
   try:
       return int(line.strip()) > 30
   except ValueError:
       return False

prev_line = None
with open ('somefile.txt','r') as f, open('newfile.txt','w') as fnew:
    for line in f:
        if line_gt_30(line) and prev_line is not None: 
            fnew.write(prev_line)
        prev_line = line
```

I haven't really tested it but it should work. It is similar to yours but it fixes a lot of your problems.

First of all you don't need to use enumerate here. I'm not sure exactly what you were getting at with print(line -1) but you need to keep the previous line in a temp variable because our file is now an iterable, meaning you can't use indexing to grab lines like in a list.

Also in startswith('1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or ... ) is equivalent to startswith('1'). You should read into exactly what or does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
final_data = [data[i-1] for i in range(len(data)) if all(b.isdigit() for b in data[i]) and int(data[i]) > 30]
```

Output:

```
['d893ecee58ee4d6f1ca56a358d2e6287', 'ae0d10efd7663c734b9ea66cec5aaa44', 'c9136ba49f4b1a8e89d6ed35cac95f7c']
```